# TypeError: Cannot read property 'scan' of undefined scanner.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to integrate `scanner-js` in my react app but I receive the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'scan' of undefined`.

You can find the code below:

```
import { scanner } from 'scanner-js';
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  scan = () => {
    scanner.scan(this.displayImagesOnPage, {
      output_settings: [
        {
          type: 'return-base64',
          format: 'jpg',
        },
      ],
    });
  };

  displayImagesOnPage(successful, mesg, response) {
    if (!successful) {
      // On error
      console.error('Failed: ' + mesg);
      return;
    }
    if (
      successful &&
      mesg != null &&
      mesg.toLowerCase().indexOf('user cancel') >= 0
    ) {
      // User cancelled.
      console.info('User cancelled');
      return;
    }
    var scannedImages = scanner.getScannedImages(response, true, false); // returns an array of ScannedImage
    for (
      var i = 0;
      scannedImages instanceof Array && i < scannedImages.length;
      i++
    ) {
      var scannedImage = scannedImages[i];
      var elementImg = scanner.createDomElementFromModel({
        name: 'img',
        attributes: {
          class: 'scanned',
          src: scannedImage.src,
        },
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.scan}>
          Scan
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

When I hover over the `scanner` object, the following things are showing, but I do not know why it's throwing an undefined error.

[image]

Can somebody help me to find the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is `\`import { scanner } from 'scanner-js'\`` - inside backticks? `\`` that's just a string, it's valid syntax but results in nothing happening, just like doing `"hello world"` on a line by itself in javascript - try `import { scanner } from 'scanner-js'`

Comment: @Bravo its a mistake while posting the question

Comment: well it would've been an explanation :p

Comment: @Bravo do you find any issue here?

Comment: Have you checked how the module is exported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're importing it wrong. If you check the [package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scanner-js), you can see that there is no exported module, so you can't import a single export (`import {scanner} from 'scanner-js'`) nor you can import the default export (`import scanner from 'scanner-js`).

You need to import the entire module for side effects only, and it will add a global `scanner` variable to the `window` object.

```
import 'scanner-js';

console.log(typeof scanner);
// => object

console.log(typeof scanner.scan);
// => function
```

If you're using ESLint, you need to add `scanner` as a [global variable](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals).

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/scanner-js-hcz2j

Comment: when I follow your approach it shows scanner  is not defined

Comment: Which one, your IDE or the browser?

Comment: I just copy the above code pasted in my IDE

Comment: I just copy the above code pasted in my IDE

Comment: I've just checked it in codesandbox and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/scanner-js-hcz2j

Comment: Are you using ESLint? If you are, you need to add scanner as a global variable: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Comment: Have you used `create-react-app` for your react app? If you did, you're using ESLint and if you're using ESLint, you need to add `scanner` as a global variable.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I think you're receiving an error like _''Failed to compile, 'scanner' is not defined  no-undef"_. Please check my answer, and add the variable as a global.

Comment: I have added it in my index ,js like import "scanner-js";
 but how can I use it anohter component

Comment: hi I have created at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-u84uje?file=src%2FApp.js can you look into please

Comment: shoud I use like this window.scanner.scan?

Comment: You can, but `scanner.scan()` will also work.